# Ant Design "onChange" API is not setting React hooks in File/Directory upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

- **What I am Using:** I am using the [**Upload**](https://ant.design/components/upload#components-upload-demo-directory) component from Ant Design to [upload a directory](https://ant.design/components/upload#components-upload-demo-directory) of files. I am using this in conjunction with the [**Progress**](https://ant.design/components/progress#components-progress-demo-circle) component of [Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/overview).
- **Desired Outcome:** I would like the **Progress** component to update while the files are being loaded to **Upload Directory** so the user can see the percentage of files that are being loaded in real time.
- **What Is Happening:** I am using React Hooks in the *"onChange"* API for the Upload Ant Design component. The *"percentageUploaded"* constant that I made works -- it correctly shows the percentage of files that have been uploaded in real time. But the *"setUploadProgress"* hook is not working. It only upates at the end when the *"percentageUploaded"* reaches 100% and the uploading process is done.
- **What I would like to happen:** In order for this component to work, I need to the *"setUploadProgress"* hook to work in real time, meaning, I need it setUploadProgress hook to store the live status of the *"percentageUploaded"* constant so the Progress component can show the live status of the upload progress.

```
export const UploadDirectory: React.FC<UploadDirectoryProps> = () => {

const [uploadProgress, setUploadProgress] = useState<number>(0);

const handleChange = (data: any) => {
  const totalFiles = filesInFolder; //filesInFolder is set from another function, it stores the total number of files being uploaded
  setFilesInFolder(totalFiles);
  setUploadingFilesCount((uploadingFilesCount += 1));
  const percentageUploaded = Math.ceil(
    (uploadingFilesCount / totalFiles) * 100
  );
  setUploadProgress(percentageUploaded); //this is the hook that I need to update while files are loading
};


return (
<div>
  <Form.Item
    label="Upload Directory"
    name={"uploadDirectory"}
  >
    <UploadFolder
     directory
     onChange={handleChange}
     fileList={fileList}
     beforeUpload={beforeUpload}
     name={"uploadFolder"}
    >
      <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Upload Directory</Button>
    </UploadFolder>
  </Form.Item>
  <Progress type="circle" percent={uploadProgress} />
</div>
)}
```

Comment: Is there a typo in the code? If assuming the constant `percentageUploaded` is `Math.ceil(uploadingFilesCount / totalFiles) * 100`, this value will always return `100` when there's at least 1 file uploaded?

Comment: @AngYC there is no type in the code. The "data" parameter in the "handleChange" function is an object with two properties: "file" and "fileList."

fileList = array of files from the computer (200 files in this case).
file = each file that is being uploaded one at a time from the fileList.

The "handleChange" function is being cycled through 200 times since there are 200 files in the fileList. the "percentageUploaded" constant is accurately updating itself with every file, I have checked. The only issue is that the "setUploadProgress" hook is not updating in this process.

Comment: Hi @HaydennHarper, the problem is `percentageUploaded` is currently an invalid JavaScript... `const percentageUploaded = Math.ceil(uploadingFilesCount / totalFiles) * 100);`, there's a missing bracket somewhere but without knowing it I cannot be sure is this the culprit of the bug.

Comment: @AngYC thank you for pointing that out. The bracket isn't missing in my VS code, it was a typo from me bringing the code onto this website. I have fixed it now in the code snippet. percentageUploaded is working as intended. It updates with the percentage of files that have been uploaded correctly. The issue is with the hook, it will not update in the "handleChange" function until the upload process is complete. So basically, the "uploadProgress" hook stays at zero the entire time files are being uploaded and only updates to "100" when the upload process is complete.